# How to build multiple containers in Jenkins file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, devops, docker-container

I have 3 different Docker images. I need to build these images from Jenkins file. I have Wildfly, Postgres, Virtuoso Docker images with individual Docker file. As of now, I am using the below command to build these images:

```
'sh docker build docker docker-compose.yml'
```

My question is how build these 3 images from Jenkins file?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: @LinPy thanks for your quick answer. Could you please let me know in the mentioned page exactly which section I need to refer? Thanks again.

Comment: are the Dockerfiles in different directories?

Comment: @agentsmith yes these are in different directories.

Comment: why not simply `docker-compose build`? I find the jenkins approach to docker images not so pleasant.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for DevOps.SE.

Comment: @LinPy .... not feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your note below your answer, you can try this simple approach without using plugins:

```cpp
stage('Building Docker Image') {
   # Creating and running the first one
   dir ('/path/to/your/directory1') {
      sh 'docker build --<docker-options> -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_1 .'
      sh 'docker run $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_1'
   }

   # Creating and running the first one
   dir ('/path/to/your/directory2') {
      sh 'docker build --<docker-options> -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_2 .'
      sh 'docker run $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME_2'
   }
}
```

or the same if you are using docker-compose

```
...
sh 'docker-compose build'
sh 'docker-compose up'
...
```

Note for your path to the Dockerfile: You are working in *jenkins workspace*!

---

There is also a plugin for this as @LinPy mentioned. Have a look at: the [Jenkins-Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) under **Using multiple containers**.

Comment: Excellent! If it helped you, can you mark the question as solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Working with pipeline better to use [Docker plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) as mentioned by @Linpy.

I assume that you already have `Dockerfile` for each image in the current workspace.

```
current_workspace/dockerdb
current_workspace/dockerapp
current_workspace/imagebla
```

Update the name of the folder as you are using local.

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Build image') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Starting to build docker image DB'
                    script {
                        def DB = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}","-f ${env.WORKSPACE}/db/Dockerfile .")
                        def nodejs = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}","-f ${env.WORKSPACE}/app/Dockerfile .") 
                        def php = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}","-f ${env.WORKSPACE}/php/Dockerfile .") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can run this once you install docker plugin @Pavan